# when I tap on TextField then key board open but TextField not sliding on top flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, textfield, sliding

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        color: AppColors.whiteColor,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            createUpperBar(context, "Patient Registration"),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              // autovalidate: true,
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 3,
                        ),
```

-------etc

how to slide press on textfield

video link  -     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zATdDJYLOdKP_Plr8DGddNbUh-48eDxw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean with your question in its current state.

Comment: ''<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>''  styles.xml file in the android/app/src/main/res/values folder

Comment: it is flutter code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Container widget with SingleChildScrollView and this will work I have tested this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Form(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```